# How do I Custom Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP (codeingiter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting

i have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 411
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91689
                            [name] => some text                            
                            [pubDate] => December 23, 2019
                        )

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91670
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 15755
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93624
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => January 02, 2019
                        )

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93621
                            [name] => some text                            
                            [pubDate] => January 02, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 15879
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91683
                            [name] => some text                          
                            [pubDate] => December 31, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 456
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93675
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => January 03, 2019
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91679
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91675
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91667
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 435
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93552
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => December 31, 2019
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91685
                            [name] =>some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91677
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and i want like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 411
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91689
                            [name] => some text                            
                            [pubDate] => December 23, 2019
                        )

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91670
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 15755
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93624
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => January 02, 2019
                        )

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93621
                            [name] => some text                            
                            [pubDate] => January 02, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 15879
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91683
                            [name] => some text                          
                            [pubDate] => December 31, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 456
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93675
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => January 03, 2019
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91679
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91667
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91675
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 435
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91685
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => December 31, 2019
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91677
                            [name] =>some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93552
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: If you could explain what the sort criteria are it would make answering the question a lot easier.

Comment: i am getting this array from loop. so, it can be more datas or less, its depends on loop.

Comment: Good for you, but that totally doesn’t answer the question you were asked just then.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Not only is your question unclear, you are also supposed to show what you have tried so far yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for the same to sort an internal array,

```
//convert to array if not,
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($arr), true);
function custom($a, $b)
{
    if(($a["album_id"] == $a["album_id"])) return 0;
    return ($a["album_id"] >= $a["album_id"]) ? -1 : 1; // interchange for order change
}
foreach($arr as &$v){
    uasort($v['data'], "custom");    
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3h0o4)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 411
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91689
                            [name] => some text                            
                            [pubDate] => December 23, 2019
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91670
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 15755
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93624
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => January 02, 2019
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93621
                            [name] => some text                            
                            [pubDate] => January 02, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 15879
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91683
                            [name] => some text                          
                            [pubDate] => December 31, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 456
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93675
                            [name] => some text                           
                            [pubDate] => January 03, 2019
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91679
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91675
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91667
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 435
            [category_name] => some text
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 93552
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => December 31, 2019
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91685
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [album_id] => 91677
                            [name] => some text
                            [pubDate] => November 23, 2019
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: it is giving me array in ascending order, but I need a custom sort like when I need i can change the index place custom and it should be different for every array.
you can see [3] =>array() , that what should the output be.

Comment: Then what's logic or criteria to change sort order?

Comment: it's like whenever we need to change the order of an array index manually so we can change easily like sometimes I need to index 1 before index 0 and sometimes i need index1 at last, it depends on requirement.

Comment: Then I can't help. You must specify something